# Android Constraint Layout not working / not responsive

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create the following layout. I've read that constraint layout is what I should to make my layout responsive. I've tried containing my constraint layout inside a linear layout hoping that the alignment would be fixed but to no avail. (not sure if what I'm doing is right)

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Here's how it looks in android studio:

[image]

Here's my xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rightwashed"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menu_btn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/burger_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/calendar_btn"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layoutDirection="inherit"
                android:src="@drawable/calendartrain"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48000002" />

            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/skillstree_btn"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layoutDirection="inherit"
                android:src="@drawable/skillstreetrain"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58000004" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/completed_btn"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layoutDirection="inherit"
                android:src="@drawable/completedtrain"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.22"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24000001" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Why must you have three different `ImageView`s?

Comment: @Jantzilla each button should open a different view that's why I have 3. I added an onClickListener to each of the three imageviews.

Comment: You should be able to use one `ImageView` and set a touch listener to retrieve coordinates and open different views depending on the location of touch.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is dependent upon the dimensions of whatever device you are emulating in the designer. When the screen size or dimensions change, you are getting a mismatch in how you puzzle pieces are lining up.

If you want to stay with the three separate then I suggest that you modify your images to fit together along the horizontal and vertical axes such that the rounded corners of the pieces fit into the corner of an enclosing `ConstraintLayout`. Once that is done, you can rotate the `ConstraintLayout` to show your tilted puzzle.

Here is an image of a quick mock-up. I have used squares instead of puzzle pieces since I don't have your images. The concept is the same though.

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:rotation="45"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```